# Как поменять почту WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, email

Помогите поменять почту в профиле WordPress. Через dashboard не выходит. Иду в general настройки и меняю адрес на нужный, но после сохранения изменений адрес снова старый. Где его найти в файлах вордпресса?

Answer (score 1):

При смене почты админа ему отправляется сообщение для подтверждения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файлах этого нет, только в базе. Таблица `wp_options`, опция `admin_email`.